# Can I configure bugzilla to email me whenever an issue is assigned to person X?

Tags: bugzilla

I want to configure BugZilla  to email me whenever an issue is assigned to one particular person. For example, if anything gets assigned to the user "critical-triage@mydomain.example.com" I want to get an email telling me so.

Is it doable?

Comment: BTW, I assume this belongs here and not on user user because bugzilla is very programming-specific.

Answer (score 1):

"Watch" the user in question.  Any event that would trigger an email to them triggers an email to you.

See section 5.10.2 of http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/userpreferences.html

Fiddling around in `Bugzilla::BugMail` to hardcode the behavior is probably something you don't want to do.

Comment: Looks good on paper, but I'm not seeing this option in my bugzilla. It says the link you sent has "The ability to watch other users may not be available in all Bugzilla installations", but my administrator doesn't know about this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Login to Bugzilla, select the Preferences link and then select the Email Preferences tab.
The User watching field is near the bottom of the page right after the table of email preferences.